# How to retrieve missing values of an id from a list?

Tags: oracle, query, subquery

have a data structure that is value/tag inside a table on Oracle sql
Lets say I have this structore

exTable

| ID | TAG | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x |
| 1 | 4 | y |
| 2 | 2 | x |
| 2 | 3 | y |
| 2 | 4 | z |

I want to retrieve the missing tags for a list of values I have, for example [1,2,3,4,5]

In this case Im searching for this as an output if I look for (1,2)

| ID | MISSINGTAG |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |

Been trying with temp tables and joins but im still missing something because when i try to join I either dont get anything or just get the ones that do exists, I achieved want I want for one id using a minus

select column_value as COL_NAME
from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('1',
'2',
'3',
'4',
'5'))
MINUS
SELECT TAG FROM exTable WHERE ID='1';

But for doing it for a list of IDS im have not had luck

If im duplicating the question let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is the create the cartesian product between your tags and existing id:s. From there you can subtract your existing table either by MINUS as in your example, or by EXISTS:

```
with d (tag, id) as (
    select tag, id 
    from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')) t 
    cross join ( 
        select distinct id from extable 
    )
) 
select * from d
where not exists (
    select 1 from extable x where x.id = d.id and x.tag = d.tag
);
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much, I was missing the cross join creating the temp table

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow your examples, if you could clarify them a little it might help, but in general it sounds like you're trying to find what data exists in one table but not another? If so, then you want to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-left-join/) and a `WHERE` clause that filters on the missing records like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableWithAllRecords
LEFT JOIN TableMissingRecords
    ON TableWithAllRecords.KeyField = TableMissingRecords.ForeignKeyField
WHERE TableMissingRecords.ForeignKeyField IS NULL
```

Comment: Im working with just 1 table exTable, and using another temp one with the list of tags[1,2,3,4,5], this tagsdo exists on the exTable but for some ids, I want to find for each id what tag they lack, in this example, 1 doesnt have the 2,3 and5 tag and 2 doesnt have the 1 and 5 tag, did that help?

Comment: Whenever I see those sorts of questions I always wonder whether this is just an hypothetical example (or an exam question) or there is some business case behind it. If the latter, what is it ? It is always better to explain the real-life business context where this question needs solving. Like: what does the table describe ? What do the tags actually mean ?